# Logging from bash in Docker: logger error: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, docker, logging

I am trying to configure logger to my script

```
#! /bin/bash

alias log="logger -s -t conf_nginx"
exec >> /var/log/myscript/file.log
exec 2>&1

log "this a log message"
```

when I am executing this script, I only see this line in the log file

```
$ cat /var/log/myscript/file.log  
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
```

Please help

```
$cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="9" VERSION="9 (stretch)" ID=debian HOME_URL="debian.org/&quot; SUPPORT_URL="debian.org/support&quot; BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.debian.org/&quot;
```

Comment: As a hint on how you'd go about debugging this yourself -- does `bash -x yourscript` show it invoking `logger` or `log` when the command in question is reached?

Comment: Btw.: Replace `var/` by `/var/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### On Docker

Because a Docker container has its own filesystem namespace, the `/dev/log` socket from the host won't be available within -- and because best-practice in the Docker world is to have each container only running a single service, there generally won't *exist* a separate log daemon inside the local container.

Best practice is to just log to the container's stdout and stderr. Thus, instead of running `logger -s -t conf_nginx "this is a log message"`, just `echo "this is a log message" >&2`.

#### On Shell Aliases

Aliases are a facility intended for interactive use, not scripting, and are in some shells turned off by default in interactive mode. Use a function instead:

```
log() { logger -s -t conf_nginx "$@"; }
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I still get the error `logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory`

Comment: What does `bash -x yourscript` show being invoked? If it's `logger`, then we have a question about your specific operating system's implementation of that external command (which is *not* part of bash itself), not a question about bash.

Comment: `+ log 'This is a log message'
+ logger -s -t conf_nginx 'This is a log message'
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
`

Comment: So we *are* calling `logger`, and logger doesn't work. But bash is doing its part fine -- you'd have the same problem if you were invoking `logger` from Python or Perl or C or [...]

Comment: cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Comment: You'll want to edit those details into the question -- though I might argue that this may belong more on ServerFault than StackOverflow, depending on the details. Still, we can try to narrow down those details a bit before making the determination...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153988/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-curioustechie).