# No /dev/log present in docker image of ubuntu:18.04 used in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using the docker image ubuntu:18.04 in my bitbucket pipeline to run my unit tests written in python language . But while running the tests there is a logging error since the code is unable to connect to a socket
I would like to know how to have rsylog and /dev/log in the ubuntu docker image ? or how to write the logger info logs from my python code to the appropiate location in the docker

[image]

Comment: You don't need `/dev/log` in the container, log to stdout/stderr instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125024/7191047

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging from bash in Docker: logger error: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124960/logging-from-bash-in-docker-logger-error-socket-dev-log-no-such-file-or-dire)

Comment: thanks @DanilaKiver I was able to solve the error by your link