# Log to journald using logger and access logs using journalctl in a Docker container

Tags: docker, logging

I am creating a suite of `bash` scripts designed to run headless on Ubuntu on bare metal. Throughout this suite, I use `logger` to send status updates to the log at various priority levels, and even use `logger --stderr` to send messages to the console and log.

I have a fully functional Bats test suite for the completed parts that I run locally, and I'm trying to get things set up with GitLab CI to lint, syntax check, and run the tests on every push.

The problem is, `logger` fails in Docker containers with the following message, so my tests fail.

```
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
```

Searching for a solution to this issue is complicated by the fact that most results are for how to move "logs" from the Docker runtime to the Docker host (`--log-format`), those "logs" are really just `stdout`/`stderr`, and the fact that there appears to be no working `journald` or `journalctl` in the containers I've used.

The script is not and will never be designed to run in a container, so the answer to [just switch to `echo "" >&2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124960/logging-from-bash-in-docker-logger-error-socket-dev-log-no-such-file-or-dire) is not applicable.

I also can't just mock `logger` because one Bats test is of the logging functions I use, and it tests them using special features of `logger` (argument, pipe, and file-to-log) then verifies the logs were written properly using `journalctl`.

How can I get `logger` and `journalctl` to work in a Docker container, meaning for `logger "MSG"` to write a log inside the container and `journalctl` to view that log inside the container?

Comment: A container only runs a single process.  If it's expecting `/dev/log` to be a Unix socket connected to a syslog daemon, that daemon isn't running inside the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze Your comment is low quality. It is a gross oversimplification (code in a container can never fork? can never thread? can never execute a command in the background with `&`?) and does not address the problem I have (getting my tests requiring `logger` to run successfully in a container).

Comment: It's certainly possible to, say, run multiple processes in a container using supervisord, or to share the socket across multiple containers using volume mounts.  But if you look at the various official images, in between the language-runtime images and prepackaged software like `nginx` or `postgres`, these images _only_ run the single process.  As you've written it, it sounds like you're expecting the container to run system daemons, and it doesn't unless you arrange to run them yourself (with the complexities that entails).

Comment: @DavidMaze Great! It sounds like you are starting to understand my question. Right now I'm looking at `ubuntu:rolling` for my CI image, not a single-service (which is not the same as "process") container, since I'm targeting my personal Ubuntu version, which I update every 6mo. So how can I get `logger` to work natively in that `ubuntu` container? `journalctl` isn't present--would installing `systemd` work or is it impossible to create `/dev/log` inside the container in GitLab.com CI?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution that works for me. Plus I've seen hints that I may be able to get to a full solution. If so, I will edit this answer in the future.

[The first line of this distantly related answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1069380/68342) made me realize what the likely solution was: Create my own socket at `/dev/log`!

[To do that from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/151040/10542), the [`socket`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/socket/socket.1.en.html) command (from 1992!) provides the means.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, in `bats:before_script` I added the following.

```yaml
- apt-get --assume-yes update
- apt-get --assume-yes install socket
- socket -b -s -l /dev/log
- logger "Testing1"
- logger "Testing2"
- logger "Testing3"
- logger "Testing4"
```

Breaking down the commands.

- Generate the `apt` caches so `apt-get` works
- Install `socket`
- Run `socket` to create our fake log socket

  - `-b` - backgrounds it
  - `-s` - creates a server
  - `-l` - "loops", or allows more than one connection per `socket` execution
- Test `socket` 4 times

As I was dialing in the options, I found that running `logger` 4 times hangs the job if the socket has not been properly created, possibly due to overloading the [socket's kernel buffer](https://medium.com/swlh/getting-started-with-unix-domain-sockets-4472c0db4eb1).

This brought me from 234 test failures to 49--and 18 of those are testing my logging functions. I have used [Bats test tag filters](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writing-tests.html#filtering-execution) to exclude them from the CI run of Bats. The remaining 31 failures appear to be due to other issues with the Docker environment.

One error message from my test suite seems to indicate that `journalctl` **IS** working and available (it wasn't before my original question, somehow). So I may be able to attach my new socket to it so everything works.